# Calling Parent Class Method inside Daughter Class

Tags: java, class, methods, parent-child

I created a private class(Class AB) inside a class(Class A).Class A has a method which I am calling inside the private class(Class AB). but I am getting error for ";" for nothing where the method calling statment is.

```
public class ClassA
{
  .........
 ....
 public void Check()
   {
  .....
 }

private class ClassAB
{
  ... 
   public void callCheck()
  {
     check();// I am getting error here
   }
}
}
```

What is the reason for this error?

[image]

How ever if I remove this method call this error goes away..

Can't I call the parent class function inside daughter class, which is automatically inheriting all the stuff from parent class..

Regards

Comment: This shouldn't even compile...can't have spaces in the class name...

Comment: Can you post the code where you are actually calling the method?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong. Anyway have a look at the below:

*As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.*

*Objects that are instances of an inner class exist within an instance of the outer class. 
Consider the following classes:*

```
  class OuterClass {
        ...
        class InnerClass {
            ...
        }
    }
```

*An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its enclosing instance. The next figure illustrates this idea.*

More info at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top

Comment: what about anonymous inner classes? they need to use the "qualified this"

Comment: But neither enclosing nor inner class is a static class. So what should I do

Comment: @UmerFarooq can you post the code in your screen shot. i think you are missing something in the example you posted here.